# A set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points.

Tags: real-analysis

> A set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points.

Proof in book: Suppose $S$ is "not closed". We must show that $S$ does not contain all its limit points. Since
$S$ is "not closed", $S^c$ is "not open". Therefore there is at least one element $x$ of $S^c$ such that every ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ contains at least one element of $S$ ...

Why is there at least one element $x\in S^c$ such that every open ball contains at least one element of the open set $S$?

Comment: That's a border point. But without assumptions to $S$, this is false, since both $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R^n$ are both open and closed.

Comment: From the excerpt you've given, I'd say *that proof is wrong*. It seems like it wants to proceed by contradiction for the $\impliedby$ direction: it's supposing that a set $S$ is not closed, then it wants to show that $S$ does not contain all its limit points. The problem is that
$$S\text{ is not closed}$$
is an *entirely different thing* than
$$S\text{ is open}$$
Indeed, a set can be open and closed; a set can also be neither open nor closed.

Comment: @ZevChonoles so $S$ is not closed does **not** mean "S is open"? That is so confusing.

Comment: @Tom: It's an unfortunate choice of terms, but it is so established that there's no chance of it changing. Best to get used to it. [See here on Wikipedia for instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#Open_and_closed_are_not_mutually_exclusive).

Comment: @Tom: Ah, did you make this change to the excerpt? I was surprised that a book would make this mistake.

Comment: @ZevChonoles The book did actually say "not closed" instead of "open" but I naively assumed them to be the same thing. But with that said, why is there at least one element $x\in S^C$ such that every open ball contains at least one element of the open set $S$?

Comment: @Tom Consider $[1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. It is not closed, but it is also not open as there is no ball around $1$ contained in $[1,2)$.

Comment: *Sets are not doors*. A set can be open, closed, open *and* closed, and neither open nor closed. [This made Hitler angry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw) ;-)

Comment: See $\:$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_space . $\;\;\;$

Comment: @Tom I wrote an answer; do you know what a contraposition is?

Comment: @kahen That was so funny! That is exactly how I felt. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @kahen: The Nazis did kill some topologists, most notably Hausdorff committed suicide to avoid the death camps,and Lindenbaum was killed in Vilnus (although the latter was more of a logician).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the edit, everything is fine. Since
$$A \text{ open} \Leftrightarrow A^C \text{ closed}$$
$S^C$ is not open, but an open set is characterised by
$$\forall\ x \in A\ \exists\ \epsilon > 0 \ : \ B_\epsilon (x) \subset A$$
The contraposition is
$$\exists\ x \in A\ : \forall\ \epsilon > 0 : B_\epsilon(x) \cap A^C \neq \emptyset$$
Which is what is stated in the book.

Comment: Alex what do you mean by contraposition and did you mean the intersection $=$ instead of $\ne$?

Comment: Contraposition of "open" is "not open". It's some form of a negation. Also, my notation works. It basically means $$B_\epsilon(x) \not\subset A$$

Comment: Hmm, this may take me a few minutes to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 2):

$S$ is closed iff $S=\overline{S}$. There is a theorem says $x\in\overline{S}\leftrightarrow\forall U(U\mathrm{\ open}\wedge x\in U\rightarrow U\cap S\neq\emptyset)$. We show $\overline{S}=S\cup S'$ ($S'$ denote the derived set). For $``\supseteq"$, note $S\subseteq\overline{S}$ and if $x\in S'$, then every neighborhood of $x$ intersect $S$ in a point different from $x$, so using the previous theorem, $x\in\overline{S}$. For $"\subseteq"$, suppose $x\in\overline{S}\setminus S$, by the previous theorem, every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $S$, but $x\notin S$ implies it must intersect $S$ in a point different from $x$, so $x\in S'$.

So $S$ closed implies $S'\subseteq S$. and if $S'\subseteq S$, we infer $S=\overline{S}$. QED

Reference: Theorem 17.6, 17.7 of Topology by Munkres, James.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $S$ converging to an element $x$ not contained in $S$. Then as a consequence of the definition of convergence, every ball centered at $x$ contains infinitely many elements of $x_n$ (we only need at least 1 for the following argument). Since $x_n$ are not elements of the complement of $S$, this means that the complement of $S$ is not open. This means that $S$ is not closed.

Conversely: Suppose $S$ is not closed.
This means the complement of $S$ is not open.
This means that there exists an $x$ contained in the complement of $S$ such that there doesn't exist a ball centered at $x$ that is contained in the complement of $S$. Hence every ball centered at $x$ intersects with $S$.
Hence there exists a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $x$ defined by taking an element from $S$ contained in the ball centered at $x$ with radius $\frac1n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

For the converse. Assume that S contains its limit points.so if x is in S' then x is in S. Recall that Closure(S)= S U S'. Since Closure of S is the smallest closed set containing S 
i.e S ⊆ Closure(S). Thus, S is closed.

Comment: Please use [$\rm \LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).